# How to get the permission

Tags: .net, sharepoint, permissions

I got the roleid from some operation. How could i know what is the permissions from it? for example: 107374182731GUIDOP

What is the permission "1073741827" represent?

Comment: How did you retrieve it? The question is very unclear. Specify what you are doing, how you are doing it, and where you want to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

this will be held in the RoleDefinition class with the RoleDefinition.Id property

```
using  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
foreach(RoleDefinitions roleloop in YOURSITE.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions)
{
 if(roleloop.Id == "YOUR ROLE ID")
 {
   Response.Write("Role name is: " + roleloop.Name);
 }
}
```